# c++ copy (reference) constructor and move constructor of class cohabitation

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, move-semantics, constructor-overloading

Here code showing the intent:

```
template<typename T>
class B 
{
  public:
  // this should indeed set t_ as a reference to t
  B(T& t):t_(t){}
  // this should instead set t_ as a copy of t
  B(T&& t):t_(t){}
  T& t_; // maybe type should be something else ?
};

A a;
B b1(a); // fine
B b2(A()); // problem
```

Would it be possible ?

Comment: You can't have both a copy and a reference.  You need to pick one or the other.

Comment: Do you want something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf975b14bd12c5bb)?

Comment: Do you want both `b1` and `b2` have the same type or not?

Comment: Btw, `B b2(A());` is vexing parsing, should be `B b2{A()}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 still need to get my head around it, but feels like what I want. Why not proposing as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, with [Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), you might do:

```
template<typename T>
class B 
{
public:
  B(T&& t):t_(t){}
  T t_;
};

template <typename T> B(T&) -> B<T&>;
template <typename T> B(T&&) -> B<T>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf975b14bd12c5bb)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you want both `b1` and `b2` have the same type, `B<A>`.

If so, you can <s>ab</s>use `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;

B(T &src) : ptr(std::shared_ptr<T>(), &src) {}
B(T &&src) : ptr(std::make_shared<T>(srd::move(src))) {}
```

---

If you don't like this solution, you can do something like this:

```
std::optional<T> storage;
T &ref;

B(T &src) : ref(src) {}
B(T &&src) : storage(std::move(src)), ref(*storage) {}
```

Note that in this case you need custom copy/move constructors, otherwise your class won't conform to [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

You can also use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::optional` here.