# c++ : how to remove cv-qualifiers of a type to access class functions?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, constexpr, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

Here an example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, 
         typename ... Args>
void print(T&& t, Args&& ... args)
{
    // line where compilation fails when the A::run is called
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&T::display),T*,Args...>)
      {
          t.display(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "not applicable !" << std::endl;    
    }
}

template<typename T>
class A 
{
    public:

    A(T&& t):t_(t){}

    template <typename... Args>
    void run(Args&& ... args)
    {
        print<T,Args...>(t_,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    T t_;
};

template <typename T> A(T&) -> A<T&>;
template <typename T> A(T&&) -> A<T>;

class B 
{
  public:
  B(int value):value_(value){} 
  void display(int a, int b)
  {
      std::cout << value_ << " " 
                << a << " " 
                << b << std::endl; 
  }
  int value_;
};

int main()
{
    int v1=10;
    int v2=20;

    B b1{1};
    A a1{b1};
    a1.t_.display(v1,v2);

    A a2{B(2)};
    a2.t_.display(v1,v2);

    //a1.run(v1,v2); // (1)
    //a2.run(v1,v2); // (2)
    //a1.run(v1);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles and runs fine. But if the 3 last lines (calls to `run()`) are un-commented, the following compilation error occurs:

(1)

> > main.cpp:7:48: error: ‘display’ is not a member of ‘B&’
> >
> > ```
> > if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&T::display),T*,Args...>)
> > ```

(2)

> > main.cpp:27:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘print(B&, int&, int&)’
> >
> > ```
> >     print<T,Args...>(t_,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
> > ```

Note :

```
template <typename T> A(T&) -> A<T&>;
template <typename T> A(T&&) -> A<T>;
```

explained here:

[c++ copy (reference) constructor and move constructor of class cohabitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571349/c-copy-reference-constructor-and-move-constructor-of-class-cohabitation)

Comment: `std::decay_t` works fine, [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/HEcuwg).

Comment: @rafix07 I am confused, this does solve (2) for me (c++17) : https://onlinegdb.com/Byx2vo9brU

Comment: @rafix07 actually it works on my machine, gcc 7.4. I wonder why it does not work on gdb online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem (1) and (2) are different problems.

Problem (1) come from the fact that in the following `std::is_invocable_v`

```
template<typename T, 
         typename ... Args>
void print(T&& t, Args&& ... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&T::display),T*,Args...>)
    //  no T but std::decay_t<T> ...............^...........^
```

instead of `T` (that can be a reference) you need the "decayed" type

I propose

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void print (T && t, Args && ... args)
 {
   using U = std::decay_t<T>;

   if constexpr ( std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&U::display), U*, Args...> )
      t.display(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   else 
      std::cout << "not applicable !" << std::endl;    
}
```

Problem (2) come from the fact that explicating the template parameters in the following `print()` call

```
template <typename... Args>
void run(Args&& ... args)
{
    print<T,Args...>(t_,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

you impede the correct template deduction.

Suggestion: let template deduction, and perfect forwarding, works and call the function as follows

```
    print(t_,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Comment: This works. For (2), while I can understand template deduction may be wiser, I remain confused why print<T,Args...> does not compile

Comment: @Vince - not sure but... when you declare `a2`, the argument is a `B&&`, so (deduction guide) `a2` become `A<B>`; so `T` is `B`; calling `print()` explicating `T`, you say that the type `T`, in `print()`, is `B`; but `t`, in `print()`, is a `T &&`, so become `B &&`; but you pass to `print()` the `t_` member; so you pass a `B &` to a function waiting a `B &&`.